# Is it possible to restrict Wordpress index page to logged in users?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to make all my articles publicly accessible but in order to view the index page, a user must first register with the site. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement in a particular page you can use the following:

To limit the access to one particular page (or some pages) so that only logged in users can reach it, I make a new page template for that purpose and then I put this bit of code in the beginning of the template (right after the  ):

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
nocache_headers();
header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
header('Location: ' . get_settings('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
header("Status: 302 Moved Temporarily");
exit();
}
?>
```

the above example is taken from [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/restrict-access-level-to-specific-post-or-page)

Additionally, you can use any one of the several wordpress plugins out there. One example is [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pagerestrict/). I have used this plugin before and it works pretty well. There are other similar plugins with varying features. A simple google search would give you lots of options.

Comment: Ultimately I wouldn't do a 302 header but your approach makes a lot of sense. An alternative approach here: do conditional templates around the method you mentioned `is_user_logged_in()`

Comment: That's right! The conditional templates approach gives a  good granular control over parts of the page you would want to hide/display.